# R: Fixest class models bloat in size when saved

Tags: r, compression, bigdata, fixest

I am currently working with a big dataset (n>10 million). I found fixest package very helpful to run logit fixed-effects models fast (feglm).

```
f1 <- feglm(result ~ log(rate1) + 
sex + 
age + 
development + 
pop + 
acad + 
size | state, se= "standard",  family=c("logit"), lean =TRUE, mem.clean = TRUE, data=total)
```

The initial problem was that my models were too big. I've tried slimming them down with `lean=TRUE` and `mem.clean=TRUE`. I've also to wiped out the linear predictors and working residuals components of the model like so:

```
f1$linear.predictors <- NULL
f1$working_residuals <- NULL
```

By doing all these steps, I managed to trim A LOT of fat. The model was originally 1.2 GB but I managed to whip it down to ~200kb

```
print(object.size(f1), units = "auto")
218.3 Kb
```

Problems arise when I try to save the model as an rda file.
The saving operation should take a split second. Instead, it takes minutes and saves the model as a bloated 300 MB file.

What am I doing wrong? I would like to keep the fixest object in its small 220 Kb size.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you Laurent B. for pointing me to the right direction. I built on your suggestion and set a couple of the model's components to `NULL`.

```
f1.1$linear.predictors <- NULL
f1.1$working_residuals <- NULL
f1.1$family <- NULL
f1.1$fml <- NULL
f1.1$fml_all <- NULL
f1.1$family$family = "binomial"
f1.1$family$family = "logit"
f1.1[["fml"]][[2]] = "emigration"
```

Thank you for your help and for creating the wonderful package that fixest is.

Comment: Thanks for the kind words :-)

Answer (score 0):

Set `family`, `fml` and `fml_all` to `NULL` and it should work.

The issue is that these items *refer* to environments even though they do not *include* the environments.
However, when save is applied, the environments to which these values refer are also saved, leading to the large file size.

This is an issue I'll try to solve in the package. Btw the items `linear.predictors`
and `working_residuals` will be appropriately erased in the next version of the package (0.10.2).

Comment: ```
f1$linear.predictors <- NULL
f1$working_residuals <- NULL
f1$family <- NULL
f1$fml <- NULL
f1$fml_all <- NULL
```
I implemented the suggestions. It works half-way. On the plus, saving is now fast. The file does not bloat in size.
However, now I cannot longer run fixest package’s etable(f1) command. This is kinda of a bummer since I am building my tables in Latex. When I run command
```
etable(f1,  tex= TRUE)
```
Error message
```
Error in if (family$family == "poisson" && family$link == "log") { : missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
```
What do you?
Thanks